# jQuery text selection event

Tags: jquery, events

I have the following event handling code:

```
$('#main').delegate('.slide', 'click', function () {
  slideshow.next();
});
$('#main').delegate('a', 'click', function (e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

`.slide` is a large div with content. `slideshow.next()` is called when `.slide` is clicked, except when a link is clicked, in which case `stopPropagation()`, and `.slide` never receives the click event.

I'd like to make it possible to select text on the slide. At the moment, if I click and drag, when I release the mouse the selection works but `.slide` registers the click and fires the `slideshow.next()` function. Is there an event I can intercept?

The page is [available here](http://skilldrick.co.uk/tmpl/).

---

**Edit:** Interestingly, if the selection spans more than one HTML element, `click` isn't fired, but it the selection is within an element, it is fired.

---

**Edit2:** Ok, here's my solution:

```
function setupHandlers() {
  var prevX = 0;
  var prevY = 0;

  $('#main').delegate('.slide', 'click', function (e) {
    var clickTolerance = 2;
    var dx = Math.abs(e.pageX - prevX);
    var dy = Math.abs(e.pageY - prevY);
    //if mouse has moved less than two pixels in any direction this is a click
    if (dx < clickTolerance && dy < clickTolerance) {
      slideshow.next();
    }
  });
  $('#main').delegate('.slide', 'mousedown', function (e) {
    prevX = e.pageX;
    prevY = e.pageY;
  });
  $('#main').delegate('a', 'click', function (e) {
    //Clicks on links shouldn't fire '.slide'.click() above
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the difference between a single click and a click that selects text ?

I would say it could either relate to the time passed between the down click and the upclick of the mouse.  Alternatively and perhaps more importantly it could be diagnosed by difference in the screen position of the mouse at the time of the down click and at the time of the mouse up event.

When the mouseDown event is fired record the event.pageX and event.pageY values.
When the mouseUp event is fired compare the stored x,y coords with the current. If they are different it was a text select... do nothing. If they are the same, swap your page.

Not sure how to implement this in JScript unfortunately ;)

Comment: I've gone with this solution - updated the question with my working code. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

use `$('.slide').select` to catch the selection event and stop propagation.

Comment: I don't want to vote this down but it's the wrong answer - .select is for form text selection, not for general text selection.